# Copy directories while changing Unicode filenames to ASCII

Tags: beginner, file-system, unicode, raku

I created a short Perl 6 script `copyfnameascii.pl` to copy a file hierarchy I have, applying an URL Decoding to the names of folders and removing non-ASCII characters from the names of files.

```
$ cd workingdirectory
$ perl6-m ../copyfnameascii.pl project copy
```

It is best illustrated by the following diagram:

> ```
>                              $ tree
>                              .
>                              ├── copy
>                              │   ├── folder 1
> $ tree                       │   │   ├── cr.txt
> .                            │   │   └── es.txt
> └── project                  │   └── folder 2
>     ├── folder%201           │       ├── ai.txt
>     │   ├── čř.txt           │       └── zy.txt
>     │   └── ěš.txt   ~*>     └── project
>     └── folder%202               ├── folder%201
>         ├── áí.txt               │   ├── čř.txt
>         └── žý.txt               │   └── ěš.txt
>                                  └── folder%202
>                                      ├── áí.txt
>                                      └── žý.txt
> ```

I just started using Perl. I'd like to hear your advice how to make the code generally better; more readable, idiomatic, and so on. The script does work; there is just a few things I am not satisfied with.

```
use Inline::Perl5;
my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;
$p5.use('Text::Unidecode');

sub transformdirname($dirname is copy) {
  $dirname.=subst( /:i \%(<[0..9A..F]>**2) /, { chr(:16(~$0)) }, :g ); # undo URL encoding
  $dirname.=subst( /\//, '_', :g ); # make it a valid UNIX filename
  return $dirname;
}

sub transformfilename($filename) {
  return $p5.call('Text::Unidecode::unidecode', $filename); # make it ASCII at all costs
}

sub MAIN($fromdir, $todir) {
  for dir($fromdir) -> $subdir {
    unless $subdir ~~ :d {
      next;
    }
    my $tosubdir = $todir ~ '/' ~ transformdirname($subdir.basename);
    say $tosubdir;
    mkdir($tosubdir);
    for dir($subdir) -> $file {
      my $tofile = $tosubdir ~ '/' ~ transformfilename($file.basename);
      if $tofile.path ~~ :e {
        die("Will not overwrite $tofile");
      }
      copy($file, $tofile);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a good task. Scroll down [in this answer on so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/801553) to the pure unicode-related false assumptions – you're breaking quite some of them.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Can you give me the numbers of a few of them you think I am breaking? I know that directory names are in English, therefore all ASCII, so no Unicode problems there. If it wasn't true, I guess I'd just have to treat what the line `# undo URL encoding` gives me as bytes and decode it with UTF-8. I still believe that regarding the file names I am doing everything correctly.

Comment: It is not a good task. But it is a necessary one. If I didn't romanize the file names, the project tracing web service where I upload the files would do it for me, replacing all UTF-8 runes that is not ASCII with underscores and adding suffixes to eliminate duplicite filenames. Then the files would be named '__1.txt', '__2.txt' and so on. I can't have that.

Comment: You're right, it's just 42 – 47 is worth considering. for the files `e.txt, è.txt ê.txt`, your file won't do anything (it would `die`). If you really want ascii only filenames, you could double URI encode it, while not nice, you're at least guaranteed to have distinctive filenames. Furthermore, as you mentioned web services, [javascript has a built-in URI-decode function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

Comment: 47 is news4me. (1) `Text::Unidecode` has a good rationale for Unicode to ASCII conversion. (2) I prefer nice filenames over guaranteed distinctive filenames. That's the whole reason why I am running this script instead of letting the webservice do the job its way (underscores). I'll always be there to manually fix the file names if the script ever `die`s, if that happens too often, I'd extend it to append distinguishing suffixes or whatever. It never died on actual input yet. This is a non-issue. Thanks for thoroughly reviewing line 12 of the script, but this is not what the question asks for

Comment: Well, maybe it actually does. Should've stressed the readable and idiomatic parts more and possibly leave "generally better" out.

Comment: That's why I left it to the comments and didn't write a review. Sorry if I upset you. I think it will be hard to find somebody grading the idiomaticity  of a program written in a language that is barely used in the wild. Good Luck! (If there still is no review in two days, I might give it a shot, I have at least used  perl6 a few times).

Comment: I apologize. I should've kept in mind that people comment only because they like to and even if I could stop them talking about things I am not interested in, there is no way I could making them comment about things I am interested in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My overall take was "Nice!". :)

Given your exchange with Patrick J S above (not to mention my lack of familiarity with the wrinkles discussed in the relevant RFCs) I'm not going to comment at all on the technical-compliance-with-standards aspects of your decoding logic.

## Simplify `Inline::Perl5` code

```
use Inline::Perl5;
my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;
$p5.use('Text::Unidecode');
.
.
sub transformfilename($filename) {
  return $p5.call('Text::Unidecode::unidecode', $filename);
}
```

That was old style. Write this way instead:

```
use Text::Unidecode:from<Perl5>;

sub transformfilename($filename) {
  return Text::Unidecode::unidecode($filename);
}
```

## [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

```
sub transformdirname($dirname is copy) {
  $dirname.=subst( /:i \%(<[0..9A..F]>**2) /, { chr(:16(~$0)) }, :g );
  $dirname.=subst( /\//, '_', :g );
  return $dirname;
}
```

This has 'dirname' in the sub's name plus four mentions of `$dirname`. Sometimes repeats are valuable, perhaps making code easier to read or change, but in this case I think the reverse applies. I'd write:

```
sub transformdirname($_ is copy) {
  .=subst( /:i \%(<[0..9A..F]>**2) /, { chr(:16(~$0)) }, :g )
  .=subst( /\//, '_', :g )
}
```

`transformfilename` has a similar issue:

```
sub transformfilename($filename) {
  return $p5.call('Text::Unidecode::unidecode', $filename);
}
```

('filename' is written three times.) In addition it's a one line routine introducing the abstract "transform" and I'm going to assume the transformation is unlikely to change, so abstracting it out to a `sub` is questionable. In addition there's *another* several 'file's in the call so instead I'd elide the `sub` altogether and eliminate *all* the repeats of 'file'. We'll see that later in the final version where I've made some additional changes.

## Comments

Imo good code means good comments. You've written good comments like:

```
sub transformdirname($dirname is copy) {
  $dirname.=subst( /:i \%(<[0..9A..F]>**2) /, { chr(:16(~$0)) }, :g ); # undo URL encoding
  $dirname.=subst( /\//, '_', :g ); # make it a valid UNIX filename
  return $dirname;
}
```

In Raku you can effortlessly turn such ordinary end-of-line comments (that start with `#`) into [Pod declarator comments](https://docs.raku.org/type/Pod::Block::Declarator) (that start with `#|` or `#=` and appear immediately before or after a declaration):

```
#| undo URL encoding and make it a valid UNIX filename
sub transformdirname($_ is copy) {
  .=subst( /:i \%(<[0..9A..F]>**2) /, { chr(:16(~$0)) }, :g );
  .=subst( /\//, '_', :g );
}
```

Now documentation tools can automatically extract documentation of the `sub` because this:

```
say &transformdirname.WHY;
```

now displays:

undo URL encoding and make it a valid UNIX filename

(Why is the method that extracts such doc called `WHY`? It's to remind folk that by far the most important thing to explain in code comments is WHY -- why the code has been written and/or why it's written the way it is.)

I note you've used `MAIN`:

```
sub MAIN($fromdir, $todir) {
```

As you know, this automatically generates a nice usage message. What you may not know is that this can be combined with the Pod declarator blocks discussed above to great effect. Checkout [The Cool subset of MAIN](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/the-cool-subset-of-main/) for examples.

## Final version

I've made many more changes to be the way I write things. As I wrote at the start, your original code looks nice and many coding issues are subjective.

```
use Text::Unidecode:from<Perl5>;

sub MAIN ($fromdir, $todir) {

  for $fromdir.dir {

    next unless .d;

    say my $tosubdir = "$todir/&transformdirname(.basename)";
    mkdir $tosubdir;

    for .dir {

      # make filename ASCII at all costs:
      my $tofile = "$tosubdir/{.basename.&Text::Unidecode::unidecode}";

      if $tofile.path.e { die "Will not overwrite $tofile" }

      copy $_, $tofile;

    }
  }
}

# undo URL encoding and make it a valid UNIX filename
sub transformdirname($_ is copy) {
  .=subst( /'%' (<xdigit>**2)/, { chr(:16(~$0)) }, :g )
  .=subst( /\//, '_', :g )
}
```